# Which loss function is the best loss function when using XGB regression with highly skewed dataset?

Tags: regression, xgboost, loss-function

Which loss function is the best loss function when using XGB regression with a highly skewed dataset?

The skewness of the data is very high. I used XGBoost with objective function of linear regression (but the data was transformed into the log space). It performed better than using gamma objective function. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you figure out a good solution for this? I asked a similar question this morning: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/75903/boosted-tree-regression-loss-function-when-data-has-occasionally-very-large-valu

Comment: I post my response here and also on your post.

Comment: Sorry, but the dataset I’m using contains some proprietary and confidential information.

Comment: The data are skewed, or the assumed conditional distribution (which you don’t observe) is skewed? Those aren’t the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could try weighting the loss for each data point, such that some datapoints do not dominate the loss.

Answer (score 0):

Since this might be a question for other people, here are the results of my findings:

I have tried two options using XGB Regression with different objective functions including:

1. A linear regression objective function ("reg:linear" or "reg:squarederror") and transformed the target to the log space
2. A gamma objective function ("reg:gamma"), which is useful for a skewed target with gamma distribution, e.g., insurance claims severity. In this case, I did not transform my target to the log space.

   In my case, option 1 performed better than option 2 (around 15-20%). However, depending on the nature of the data one of them might outperform the other one.

Also, here is one potential option as the objective function "reg:squaredlogerror"